compose how to add alignment to a Composable function child
@Composable
fun Root() {
  Box {
    Text("foo")
    BarView()
  }
}
@Composable
fun BarView() {
  Text("bar")
}

this is my code example, i want to set BarView align to TopEnd.
if i change BarView() to fun BoxScope.BarView(), then BarView cannot reuse in other widget.
if i wrap BarView with a Box, it will have an extra layer.
Box {
    Text("foo")
    Box(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd)) {
      BarView()
    }
  }

Is there a better way to do this, or wrap a Box is just fine.

You can pass in a Modifier to the BarView Composable:
@Composable
fun BarView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        modifier = modifier
        text = "bar"
    )
}

Then, you can use it in any parent Composable, but still can pass down any Modifier that requires a certain scope:
@Composable
fun Root() {
    Box {
        Text("foo")
        BarView(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd)  // pass BoxScope Modifier
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ColumnExample() {
    Column {
        Text("foo")
        BarView(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)  // pass ColumnScope Modifier
        )
    }
}

This approach also is best practice according to the Modifier documentation:

It's a best practice to have all of your composables accept a modifier parameter, and pass that modifier to its first child that emits UI. Doing so makes your code more reusable and makes its behavior more predictable and intuitive.

